# how to use cache in NSFetchedResultsController in Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am doing this code in my `viewDidLoad` method

```
fetchedResultCont = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: req,
 managedObjectContext: container.viewContext,
 sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
 cacheName: nil)
```

Docs said that we can use cache in order to speed up the process but there is no implementation.

Can any one please tell me that how do I use cache in place of nil in cache name to speed up the process ?

Answer (score 0):

You simply specify a string that will be used as the name of the cache directory.

```
fetchedResultCont = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: req,
     managedObjectContext: container.viewContext,
     sectionNameKeyPath: "SectionKey",
     cacheName: "MyCache")
```

However, as you aren't using sections in your fetch request, the cache won't benefit you:

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontroller/1622282-init)

> The name of the cache file the receiver should use. Pass nil to prevent caching.
>
> Pre-computed section info is cached to a private directory under this name. If Core Data finds a cache stored with this name, it is checked to see if it matches the fetchRequest. If it does, the cache is loaded directly—this avoids the overhead of computing the section and index information. If the cached information doesn’t match the request, the cache is deleted and recomputed when the fetch happens.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but actually I am not using section just because I don't know how to add cache, if I knew it, I would have use section

Comment: can you show an example on how we proceed with cache if we have section

Comment: Ok. Specify a string for the cache, say `”MyCache”` and the name of the key  whose value determines your sections.